# Strip-tags vs htmlentities vs other. Which has the better security in php?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, security, sql-injection

I'm creating a website (assuming that it will have a lot of users) that is going to have users using all characters and so it could contain characters like `>`, `<` and `/`.

So someone suggested that I use htmlentities() instead of strip tags. Is htmlentities reasonbly safe against SQL injection? And is there an alternative more secure method that I could easily implement into my website, that's better than htmlentities and strip tags?

I would like to know what that is and whatever your solutions are, how would you personally improve this security wise in php (help of javascript is an exception too):

```
$current_password = strip_tags(@$_POST['currentpassword']);

$get_info = mysql_query ("SELECT first_name, last_name, bio FROM users 
WHERE username='$user' ");
```

That's my simple question. Cheers.

Comment: I think you're confusing cross site scripting and sql injections.  You need to research prepared statements for SQL injections.

Comment: You shouldn't be performing this transformation to passwords. You shouldn't even be storing passwords. Hash your passwords.

Comment: you might find this interesting : http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php. also as Paul said , hash your passwords instead of doing such transformations.

Comment: Neither `strip_tags` nor `htmlentities` are suitable for SQL. They are intended for HTML. Have a look at [*How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114) for a guidance on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP.

Comment: About strip_tags, if the user posts malformed html, strp_tags will not return anything in most cases. Use Tidy to clean the html before stripping the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it confused. strip_tags() should only be used when you want to remove HTML tags from a block of text. It shouldn't be applied on a user-input password. For example, if your user had a password `hello<there>`, it would strip away `<there>` and the password then would just be `hello`. This could cause a lot of problems.

Similarly, htmlentities aren't helpful against SQL injection either. This function just converts the HTML tags and characters to their entity formats, thus preventing it from causing issues while being displayed on a webpage.

To be safe against SQL injections, you don't need htmlentities or strip_tags. What you need is prepared statements. Properly prepare your query with placeholders. Also, note that mysql_* functions are now deprecated; you should use mysqli_* or PDO.

Off the top of my head, untested:

```
/* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
  exit();
}

/* Create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT first_name, last_name, bio FROM users WHERE username=?');

/* Bind parameters
         s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);

/* Execute it */
$stmt->execute();

/* Get a result set from the prepared statement */
$result = $stmt->get_result();

/* Fetch result rows as an associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, 1).'</pre>';
    // do something with $row
}
```

For more information, refer:

- [Cross Site Scripting - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)
- [Prepared Statements - PHP Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the code above in order for it to work with a prepared statement, for some reason it's not working with me. Would you be able to re-arrange the code above to a php prepared statement (mysqli and placeholders). I'll mark that as that as an answer. Cheers